How to replace `${number}` type to just string type '${number}' in TypeScript?
Let's say I have type Foo:
type Foo = 'apple' | `a.${number}` | `a.${number}.c`

Eventually I want to convert it to Boo:
type Boo = ReplaceTemplateWithLiteral<Foo>
// 'apple' | 'a.${number}' | 'a.${number}.c'

I know that I can extract string type that includes ${number} by:
Extract<Foo, `${string}.${number}` | `${string}.${number}.${string}`>
// `a.${number}` | `a.${number}.c`

But I don't know how to convert it to 'a.${number}' | 'a.${number}.c' which is just string literals.
Is this even possible?

For number specifically? That is possible, like this. For all template literals like \${T}`to"${T}"? nooooo, that's not how anything works. It's like asking TypeScript to turn a variable named abcinto the *string*"abc".  So is the use case narrow like number` or wide like arbitrary template literals?

Or are you asking how to create string literal types (that look like templates) like this?

@jcalz Sorry I don't get your last sentence, So is the use case narrow like number or wide like arbitrary template literals?. I can tell you only by showing an input type and the desired output type, which I described in the text. But yeah, it's number specifically! All template literals \...${number}...`to'...${number}...'`.

@jsejcksn Yeah, I want it like this. I used hard coding just to show what result I want.

@jcalz Your example is what I was looking for! Would you kindly post it as your answer so other people may find your solution easily?

I will post an answer when I get a chance.

Note: I'm only interested in supporting replacing the `${number}` pattern/placeholder template literal type (see microsoft/TypeScript#40598) with the string literal type "${number}". I'm not going to worry about replacing other placholder template literal types, like a generic one of the form `${T}` (where T is a generic type parameter), or `${string}`. If you have one of those in your template literal type then all bets are off.
You could do it like this:
type ReplaceNumberWithLiteral<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
  ReplaceNumberWithLiteral<R, `${A}${`${number}` extends F ? "${number}" : F}`> : 
  A;

Here we're using a tail-recursive conditional type to walking through the string literal character by character, and if it finds `${number}` then it replaces it with "${number}", and otherwise it leaves what it finds alone. Note that detecting  `${number}` is a little tricky; you can't check F extends `${number}` because if F is a numeric character like "3" then it will succeed, and you don't want to turn "ABC123" into "ABC${number}${number}${number}". I've changed it to `${number}` extends F which works for the use cases we want to support. Of course if F is `${string}` then it would succeed, and so something like `a${string}b` will probably turn into "a${number}b".  If that's important, then one could try to change the above code, but it's out of scope for the question as asked.
Let's make sure it works:
type Foo = 'apple' | `a.${number}` | `a.${number}.c`
type Bar = ReplaceNumberWithLiteral<Foo>
//   ^? type Bar = "apple" | "a.${number}" | "a.${number}.c"

Looks good.
Playground link to code
